# How can I trace log and monitor the SharePoint search queries?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

Using SharePoint 2013,

I like to trace and log the queries that the SharePoint query engine is running. 
Essentially, I am looking for something similar SQL Profiler for SharePoint search.

I am aware of SharePoint Search analytic reports, However, I am not looking for an analytics roll-up style report.  I am looking for a trace log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have it in your [usage report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219611.aspx#Proc4). In the usage report, you have all the goodies like

- Number of Queries
- Top Queries by Day
- Top Queries by Month
- Abandoned Queries by Day
- Abandoned Queries by Month
- No Result Queries by Day
- No Result Queries by Month
- Query Rule Usage by Day
- Query Rule Usage by Month

Comment: I was aware of the reports. They are aggregation of the detail log that I am trying to find. 

I am looking for the trace of the queries, including date, time, user and the actual query.

Maybe I am too much used to SQL Server Profiler and looking for the idea here in SP Search as well.